# Set or pass the value of the same parameter in the master report to multiple subreports in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have two subreports with different queries, and the two columns I would like to have the user search by have different names and I can't change the column names.

I would like to set the parameters with different values and use just two parameter in the master reports for both. meaning Master Report parameters @Name @Employee ID

Subreport 1

- has the columns Name and Empl_ID
- parameters @Name @Empl_ID

Subreport 2

- has the columns Full_Name and Employee_ID
- parameter @Full_Name @Employee_ID

I've created the parameters but the master report now has four parameters two per subreport.

Again, I would like the master report just to use two parameter and work for both subreports. is this possible?

the query `SELECT Empl_ID,Name,P,Stat_Type,Dept_ID FROM HIST_NAME WHERE (P='50') AND (Stat_Type = 'Completed') AND (Dept_ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) OR (Dept_ID BETWEEN 573 AND 593) AND (@AllActionsEmplName IS NULL) AND (@AllActionsEmplID IS NULL) OR (Dept_ID BETWEEN 573 AND 593) AND (@AllActionsEmplID IS NULL) AND (Name LIKE '%' + @AllActionsEmpName + '%') OR (Dept_ID BETWEEN 573 AND 593) AND (@AllActionsEmplName IS NULL) AND (Empl_ID LIKE '%' + @AllActionsEmplID + '%') OR  (Dept_ID BETWEEN 573 AND 593) AND (Name LIKE '%' + @AllActionsEmplName + '%') AND (Empl_ID LIKE '%' + AllActionsEmplID + '%')`

NOTE: query builder reformatted it that way

Comment: how are you directing user to the sub reports from the master report? I would imagine you can just set up your 2 parameters (name/ID) in your master report, then you can pass the parameters to both your sub reports through the property actions.

Comment: is your question a part of the homework?

Comment: i am using a drop down list for reports, and no this isn't my homework, i am actually helping someone who does the reports, i work the SSIS packages and coding, but i am not good at the reports parts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have ended up with 4 parameters in your subreport. All you need to do is in the parameter properties for each subreport, choose the name of the subreport's parameter on the left side and the name of the parameter from the master report that you want to pass in.

If this does not help, leave a comment and I will add a more complete solution.

**EDIT after feedback from OP**

IN this simple example I created 2 subreports. They are virtually identical but both take different parameter names. The data they return is not relevant.

The first subreport takes two parameters @country and @category and looks like this.
[image]

The data is filtered where country = @country and category = @category

The second subreport is almost the same but this one takes two parameters called @region and @section. Data is filtered where country = @region and category = @section

[image]

I then added a master report. This has no datasets but does have two parameters, @MasterP1 and @MasterP2. These could be called anything, even the same as one of the subreports but I called them different things for clarity.

I added two subreports, one for each of the sub reports we created.

I set the parameter properties as follows

**First subreport**

[image]

Where A is the names of the parameters the subreport expects and B is the name of the values we want to pass (in this case the parameters from the master report)

**Second subreport**

[image]

The exact same thing applies here, even though the subreport has different parameter names, we still pass the same values to it. so only the Name column changes.

That's it...

Comment: Alan, thanks for your quick response,  i am using two different datasets, one per subreport.  the parameters from the subreports dont show on the master report even though i have added both datasets to the master report as well, so the only way to see the parameters is to add them to the master report as well. i am not sure if i am doing this wrong

Comment: Usually, you don't need the datasets from the subreports in your master report. The master report does not have to know anything about the subreport other than what parameters it expects. That would explain why you get 4 parameters in the master report. Give me a little time I'll do a sample with screen shots.

Comment: ok thank you...i tried running the master report but it there was an error and it requested a dataset be assigned to the table i am using to list the reports. btw, the parameters didnt show at all on the master report for either dataset. i had to add them manually

Comment: So you are using a table to repeat the subreports? is that correct? If so, can you edit your question to show the report design and the dataset columns and explain which values you need to pass to the sub reports. I don't want to waste time posting an answer if it's not what you actually want.

Comment: i understand and would hate to waste your time, i am using two separate tables, unfortunately i cant make changes to them. the tables have mostly the same data but the column names for Employee ID and Name are different. so i had to use two separate queries.

the two columns i need to have a filter parameter for are employee_id and name

Comment: You mentioned a dataset for the table that lists the reports, that's why I'm checking if you are repeating the subreports several times or not just showing each once.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time, i rebuilt the project using your instructions, there were no errors until i tried using the filters. they dont seem to work. am i supposed to set them on the table filtering options or in dataset or both? btw, the filters dont work whether i display the subreports by themselves or via the master report. again, thank you for all your help

Comment: If you run the subreports on their own and set the prameters, do they work or not? If not then you'll have to resolve that issue first

Comment: awesome, i was editing my previous comment to make it read better. i will try to solve that...thank you

Comment: ok, i cant even seem to make it work properly in the query builder. here is the query i am using: i'll post the query in another comment, i guess its too long